# How to perform OAuth in React app to use Jira rest API

Tags: reactjs, oauth, jira-rest-api

I want to make a call to the Jira REST API to get a list of tasks for a user but I'm not really sure how to go about authenticating. All the Jira documentation suggest OAuth but I can't figure out how to implement this using React. Can anyone point me to some documentation or an example of how to perform OAuth in React? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you get any lead with that?
I also need to implement that!

Comment: not yet. I found an npm package that might have some potential but have not tested it out yet. If I find a solution I will post it here :)

Comment: same here!
but for now i am continuing with auth in nodejs!

Comment: Are you getting CORS error when trying to call REST Api's??